# how to change api calls when dropdown values changes nextjs

Tags: next.js, getstaticprops, getserversideprops

I am working on a nextjs project that is a calendar. when country and year changes calendar should change and I use a holidays API. API url contains country and year parameters(`https://localhost:5001//holiday?&country=${country}&year=${year}`). SO I need to pass country and year , In `Holiday.tsx` I use a Drop down for select country and year.

I struggled at data fetching. How Can I pass these selected country and year values to `index.tsx`. I don't use dynamic paths. I have only index.ts.

api.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GetAllHolidaysData } from "../interfaces/GetAllHolidaysData";  

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED;
const http = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API });

export const GetAllHolidays = (country: string, year: number) => {
  console.log(country, year);

  return http.get<GetAllHolidaysData>(
    `/holiday?&country=${country}&year=${year}`
  );
};
```

index.tsx

```
const Home: NextPage<{ holidays: GetAllHolidaysData }> = ({ holidays }) => {
  return (
    <>
          <Holidays holidays={holidays}/>
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  // let country = "ro";
  // let year = "2021";
  let holidays: GetAllHolidaysData;

  try {
    const { data } = await GetAllHolidays(country, year);    // I struggled at this line how to bind country and year those are selected in Holiday.tsx file using a dropdwon
    holidays = data;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return {
    props: {
      holidays,
    },
  };
};

export default Home;
```

Holiday.tsx  - conuntry and year changes here

```
const Holidays: NextPage<data> = ({ holidays }) => {
  const [selectedYear, setselectedYear] = useState(currentYear);
  const [selectedCountry, setselectedCountry] = useState(countries[169]);

  const countryChangeHanlder = (e) => {
    GetAllHolidays(e.value, year);
    // setCountry(e.label);
    setselectedCountry(e);
    console.log(selectedCountry);
  };
  const yearChangeHanlder = (e) => {
    const countryCode = Object.entries(selectedCountry)[0].map((i) => i)[1];  
    GetAllHolidays(String(countryCode), e.value);
    setYear(e.value);
    setselectedYear(e);
   
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

You can't do it in `getServerSideProps` using the selection from the dropdown, given that the dropdown is on the page you want to return using this `getServerSideProps`. Instead, you should do it in the component itself - `const Home: NextPage` or `Holiday.tsx`.

Explanation:

`getServerSideProps` is called on the server *before* the page is returned to the client. You can check it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops).

Your dropdown selection is available *after* the page is returned (and rendered), so that's where you have access to the values, hence you're able to make a request using the selection

Updated:

You could do smth like this:

```
const Holidays: NextPage<data> = ({ holidays }) => {
  const [selectedYear, setselectedYear] = useState(currentYear);
  const [selectedCountry, setselectedCountry] = useState(countries[169]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
         const { data } = await GetAllHolidays(country, selectedYear);
         // use your data from here

      } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
       })()
  }, [selectedYear])

  const countryChangeHanlder = (e) => {
    GetAllHolidays(e.value, year);
    // setCountry(e.label);
    setselectedCountry(e);
    console.log(selectedCountry);
  };
  const yearChangeHanlder = (e) => {
    const countryCode = Object.entries(selectedCountry)[0].map((i) => i)[1];  
    GetAllHolidays(String(countryCode), e.value);
    setYear(e.value);
    setselectedYear(e);
   
  };
}
```

Comment: So I cannot use getserversideprops when select parameters using dropdown? Then is there any other way to do this? When selected values changes, api Call also have to change, how to do that. Please help me

Comment: @hanu check the updated answer

Comment: Are you sure this?  I got error, 1) i can not use await. so i remove that. 2) I got like this `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<GetAllHolidaysData>>'.`

Comment: yes, because you need await :) try to wrap it in async. I'll update the answer